# Route53 records intermittently becoming invalid

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns, cname, amazon-route53, amazon-vpc

I'm using Route53 to address EC2 instances within a VPC, and I set up my subdomain and CNAME records [as described in this blog post](http://www.yobyot.com/cloud/how-to-use-aws-dns-in-a-vpc/2014/05/01/). (I'm using name.com to manage the main domain, but my setup is otherwise identical.)

At first it was working fine, but then I noticed that the domain name record intermittently becomes invalid (NXDOMAIN), then resolves properly again a while later.

I used a script to monitor this over the course of several hours, and found that the time in between is always a multiple of 300 seconds, which happens to be the TTL of the subdomain in R53.

What might be the cause, or how can I proceed to debug this?

Comment: Do you happen to have the full output of your dig?  If maybe the CNAME target that's failing to resolve and not your CNAME record.

Comment: Thanks, the end target worked. It was the CNAME record itself that was periodically returning the NXDOMAIN.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have misconfigured one of the 4 assigned "ns-xxxx.awsdns.xx" authoritative DNS servers when you pointed your domain to Route 53 with your domain registrar.

Verify those settings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I just had someone else check them and all four of them look to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

For people who encounter this in the future: I stopped using the Route53 approach, and am using this one instead: http://alestic.com/2009/06/ec2-elastic-ip-internal